# What happen when i add tow (A) row in DNS with same domain name and different target

Tags: dns, ovh

**Hello**
What happen when i add tow A row in DNS with same domain name and different target
like this in ovh dns :
[image]

because i want him to swing when overload

Answer (score 1):

When a client requests from your DNS server to resolve the name into an IP address, the server will respond with list of all 3 ip addresses (and rotate the order next time it receives request for that same name.

Client will typically use the first ip address form the list (and perhaps fail over to the next one if the first is unreachable).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS

Comment: Does TTL or something else allow you to add some priorities to the entries? What is the utility to do this, instead of having a load balancer with a unique IP DSN entry? (I believe dispatching request when having multiple entries is quite random). Thanks

Comment: Some DNS server implementations might offer this weighted round-robin functionality, but I don't think it is defined by standard. Check https://serverfault.com/questions/357650/weighted-round-robins-via-ttl-possible